# Swift : collectionView takes too long to display

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am developing an iOS application in Swift.

I display data from database inside a collectionview but it takes too much time to appear on screen. 
Surely a thread problem because on Xcode console, I can see data being displayed 20 seconds before it appears on the screen. Here is my code :
https://github.com/ProjetCedibo/projet/blob/master/Projet-L3-master/appli/SJEPG/SJEPG/CenterViewController.swift

How can I make the collectionView being displayed faster ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this happens, it means you are making UI changes from a thread other than the main thread. Try this:

```
func refresh() {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.eventsCollection.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that code is probably run on a secondary thread. Any UI changes you make should be made on the main thread. So try this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()){
    // reload your collection view here
})
```

Comment: When you want to make a change to something you've posted, use the **edit** button. Avoid the pattern of deleting + posting again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @StefanArentz answer

For Swift 3:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   // code to reload collection view
}
```